# what is the difference between image vs imagesc in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-scaling, imshow

I want to know the difference between imagesc & image in matlab

I used this example to try to figure out the difference beween the two but i couldn't explain the difference in the output images by myself; could you help me with that ?

```
I = rand(256,256);
for i=1:256

for j=1:256
    I(i,j) = j;


 end
end
figure('Name','Comparison between image et imagesc')
subplot(2,1,1);image(I);title('using image(I)');
subplot(2,1,2);imagesc(I);title('using imagesc(I)');
figure('Name','gray level of image');
image(I);colormap('gray');
figure('Name','gray level of imagesc');
 imagesc(I);colormap('gray');
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? Is there something specific you don't understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`image`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) displays the input array as an image. When that input is a matrix, by default `image` has the `CDataMapping` property set to `'direct'`. This means that each value of the input is interpreted directly as an *index to a color in the colormap*, and out of range values are clipped:

> `image(C)` [...] When `C` is a 2-dimensional `M`x`N` matrix, the elements of `C` are used as indices into the current `colormap` to determine the color. The
>       value of the image object's `CDataMapping` property determines the
>       method used to select a colormap entry. For `'direct'` `CDataMapping` (the default), values in `C` are treated as colormap indices (1-based if double, 0-based if uint8 or uint16).

Since Matlab colormaps have *64 colors by default*, in your case this has the effect that values above 64 are clipped. This is what you see in your `image` graphs.

Specifically, in the first figure the colormap is the default `parula` with 64 colors; and in the second figure `colormap('gray')` applies a gray colormap of 64 gray levels. If you try for example `colormap(gray(256))` in this figure the image range will match the number of colors, and you'll get the same result as with `imagesc`.

[`imagesc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) is like `image` but applying *automatic scaling*, so that the image range spans the full colormap:

> `imagesc(...)` is the same as `image(...)` except the data is scaled to use the full colormap.

Specifically, `imagesc` corresponds to `image` with the `CDataMapping` property set to `'scaled'`:

> `image(C)` [...] For `'scaled'` `CDataMapping`, values in `C` are first scaled according to the axes `CLim` and then the result is treated as a colormap index.

That's why you don't see any clipping with `imagesc`.

Comment: Well, what can I say, thank you so much for this clear response ! you explained this perfectly !

Comment: @YassineBakkar Glad I could help!